# matplotlib subplot2grid doesn't display correctly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using subplot2grid to display graphs. However, not all subplots are being displayed. Obviously it has to do with the if statement.
However, in my complete code I need those if statements because depending on some conditions plots have diffent formats. I want all 3 subplots to be displayed (one for each i). However, the first one is missing. How to display it correctly?

Here is the simplified code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
for i in xrange(0,3):  
    if i==1:
        ax=plt.subplot2grid((3,1),(i,0))
        ax.plot([1,2],[1,2])
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
    else:
        ax=plt.subplot2grid((3,1),(i,0), rowspan=2)
        ax.plot([1,2],[1,2])
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: mock up what it is that you'd like to see. Tough to know what you have in mind w/o picture (or even a description).

Comment: I want all 3 subplots to be displayed (one for each i). However, the first one is missing.

Comment: I still need more detail. `rowspan=2` makes me think that you want the middle axes to be half as tall as the outer axes, but you haven't really verbalized that goal.

Comment: For the simplified example I just want to plot all of those 3 axes. Yes, considering the rowspan the middle axis would be half as tall as the others. In my real world code, which is far more complex there are many if conditions and many formatings hooked to those if conditions. The problem I face is that only some or only one of the subplots is displayed, the others not. Just as in my example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the `gridspec` module from matplotlib. Then you can set the width/height ratios directly.

Then you can do something like this:

```
import numpy  
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def do_plot_1(ax):
    ax.plot([0.25, 0.5, 0.75], [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], 'k-')

def do_plot_2(ax):
    ax.plot([0.25, 0.5, 0.75], [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], 'g--')


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, height_ratios=[2, 1, 2])

for n in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[n])
    if n == 1:
        do_plot_1(ax)
    else:
        do_plot_2(ax)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

To use `plt.subplot2grid`, you'd need to effectively do something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,1), (0, 0), rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,1), (2, 0), rowspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((5,1), (3, 0), rowspan=2)
```

Since you have two axes with a `rowspan=2`, your grid needs to be 2+1+2 = 5 blocks tall.